# Simple feed icon for Firefox

Tags: firefox, notification, feed-reader

I am looking for a Firefox add-on that provides a simple feed icon.

All I want is an icon/button in the button bar that is highlighted or blinking in any way when any of my feeds has new content.

I don't want to have a feed *reader*; it should just provide the link to the original website.

Answer (score 0):

One way of setting this up would be to use the extension [Check4Change](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/check4change/). Configuring this to point to the web representation of your feeds (by which I mean the XML) should give you that notification when the content of the feed changes, without being a reader itself. This is a bit of an abuse of the plugin though, but it's simple enough to set up.

Answer (score 0):

[Feedbro](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/feedbroreader/), an extension for Firefox and Chrome, should be able to meet your most of your needs. You might want to have look at the settings for the extension to configure it the way you want.